# Log Every Request Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony application where I'd like to log every quest with `ROLE_ADMIN` in the database.  I've tried adding a new bundle, but I'm not really sure how that get's loaded in `AppKernel.php`.  Any guidance you could provide would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an event listener on `kernel.request` event and check if request comes from an user with `ROLE_ADMIN`.

First create the service and inject `security.authorization_checker` and `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`:

```
admin_log_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AdminLogListener
    arguments: [ "@security.authorization_checker", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

Then create the event listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class AdminLogListener {

    protected $authChecker;
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authChecker, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            // Use $this->entityManager to send query or call a repository function
            // Refer to http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html
        }
    }
}
```