# API Logger for Shopware 6

Tags: api, shopware6

In order to debug APIs with 3rd Parties, it is often helpful to see the API requests and responses.
For Shopware 5 there [was an extension for this purpose](https://store.shopware.com/lenz500265899551/api-logger.html).

How to log API requests and responses in Shopware 6 ?

Comment: Approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026349/log-every-request-symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which API scope you want to log requests for. There's `store-api`, `api` (commonly referred to as Admin-API) and `storefront` (not really an API in a narrower sense). If you want to log requests to just one of the scopes or log them to different file name patterns, then you could [take a look at the `RouteScopeListener`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dea144715a735c2b6f53098b9c92f9eeebc16c21/src/Core/Framework/Routing/RouteScopeListener.php) on how to retrieve the scope from the request stack.

You could then rebuild this listener in a plugin of yours and additionally inject the `logger` service. In the handler you then might check that the scope is one of those you want to log data for. Depending on that select the data from the request stack you want to log and where to log it.